# read data serially from cr3000 datalogger in python

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port

I am trying to read the data from cr3000 datalogger serially and convert into csv in python on my laptop. But when I am trying to print the decoded bytes, an invisible cursor moves in the terminal. The csv file is  generated but the data is not being written in it.Also, puTTY shows a blank screen. But the datalogger is connected via RS232 and updates the data in its software. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
import serial
import csv
import datetime
import time


ser = serial.Serial(port='COM4',baudrate=9600,timeout=1,bytesize=8,stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE) 
time.sleep(2)
ser.flushInput()
ser.write(b"Output(ScanList(), 'data.csv', , , , , , , , Append)") 




filename = 'data.csv'
fields = ['Time', 'Thermocouple']
with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(fields)

while True:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8")
        
        print(decoded_bytes)
   
   
        with open('data.csv','a') as csvfile:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 
            rows = [[time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")],[ decoded_bytes]]
            csvwriter.writerow(rows)
```